# Weak points while comparing columns in trigger as hstore-data

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

On some occasion I'd like before `UPDATE` to make sure which columns are changed. To make it as generic as possible, I don't want to use schema, table or column names in function. I found some solution here in SO and other places, and particularly liked idea to use `hstore` from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23792079/196241)

Downside of `hstore`, as said widely, is it that this way I lose data types, everything is stringified.

But using it in context of trigger (while having no complex cols like `json` or `hstore`), where both `NEW` and `OLD` have same set of cols with according datatypes, I could think of just one problem: NULL and empty values will be not distinguishable.

What other problems I may be faced with, when I detect changes in trigger function like this:

```
changes := hstore(NEW) - hstore(OLD);
```

Alternative seems to use `jsonb` and then write some `jsonb_diff` function to discover changes. `hstore`'s offered internal subtract-operation seems way more robust, but maybe I have not considered all weak points there.

I'm using Postgres 9.6.

Comment: NULL and an empty string **are** distinguishable: https://rextester.com/BPZGE67837

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ok, then I am out of weak points at all ;)