# PostgreSQL: NOTIFY when specific column is updated

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, hstore

I currently have a table in PostgreSQL that looks like this

```
my_table (id, info, data, url)
```

This is being regularly updated with a webscraper, I have attached the following triggers to notify me on updates to any record

```
cursor.execute("""
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION notify_my_table_update() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    DECLARE
    row RECORD;
    output TEXT;
    
    BEGIN
    -- Checking the Operation Type
    IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
      row = OLD;
    ELSE
      row = NEW;
    END IF;
    
    -- Forming the Output as notification. You can choose you own notification.
    output = 'OPERATION = ' || TG_OP || ' and ID = ' || row.id;
    
    -- Calling the pg_notify for my_table_update event with output as payload

    PERFORM pg_notify('my_table_update',output);
    
    -- Returning null because it is an after trigger.
    RETURN NULL;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
""")
```

and

```
# CREATE TRIGGER trigger_my_table_update
#   AFTER UPDATE
#   ON my_table
#   FOR EACH ROW
#   EXECUTE PROCEDURE notify_my_table_update();
#   -- We can not use TRUNCATE event in this trigger because it is not supported in case of FOR EACH ROW Trigger 
#   """
# )
```

This sends me an async whenever the database is updated. However, I would only like it to notify me ONLY if there is any **change** in the columns *data & url*, that is the current values are being updated to new values. My web scraper updates these values regardless if the values scraped are different from the ones in the database.

How can I achieve this? I saw Richard Huxton's [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23788530/detecting-column-changes-in-a-postgres-update-trigger) recommend hstore. However, I am having trouble figuring out how to establish an old hstore as well as a new hstore for each record of this table.

I am using Python with psycopg2 if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simpler than you think:

```
IF OLD IS DISTINCT FROM NEW THEN
   PERFORM pg_notify('my_table_update',output);
END IF;
```

Use `IS DISTINCT FROM` rather than `<>` to handle NULL values correctly.

Comment: Thank you! How can I pass the column name that is being changed into the notify.payload?
For example, I want the output to include my_data since that is the column being changed 
Currently it is:
output = 'OPERATION = ' || TG_OP || ' and ID = ' || row.id;

Comment: You could add `to_jsonb(OLD)` and `to_jsonb(NEW)` as payload, if it fits.

Comment: Also, you can use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45233132/6464308) to dynamically extract the columns from `OLD` and `NEW`, but that's not exactly cheap.